# User input to perform action

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm building a script that I want to allow for user input to take action.

Currently this tool can checked all remote servers for any automatic stopped services. I do not want the script to automatically start them though. What I would like user input to start these services.

```
Write-Host "Checking for Stopped Services..."

$stoppedServices = Invoke-Command $Servers {
    Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -ComputerName $Servers -Filter "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running'" |
        Sort state | select name, state
} -Credential $Credential

if ($stoppedServices -ne $null) {
    Clear-host
    $stoppedServices           
} else {
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host ("No stopped services found!")
}
```

So users have the ability to see the stopped services.  I want to do 2 things from this. Write out the stopped services with the option, do you want to start these stopped services?

With that option then either exit or start the service. I'd imagine I can achieve this with another `foreach` loop but can never get it work.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "but cannot get that either."? Do you receive any errors? Observed behavior v. expected behavior?

Comment: Sorry, it just flat out doesn't work. I end up with FulBox1,Box2.domain.host.  It's like showing work in a math problem. I'm completely beginning with powershell and can't seem to find what i need anywhere

Comment: This really sounds like two separate questions.. First you ask for a "confirm"-question before STARTING all the stopped services in auto-mode. And then you have a completely different script to STOP. Please be more specific and one question per SO-post.

Comment: Thanks Frode, i took out question 2.

Comment: It is and i get none.. It is part of a larger tool, this was option 1 on that tool i was building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `Get-WmiObject` instead of `Get-CimInstance`, collect the matching services in a hashtable, and pass the list into `Out-GridView` with the `-PassThru` option. The gridview will return just the objects selected by the user which you can use to call the `StartService()` method on the service object in the hashtable.

```
$svc = @{}
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Computer $Servers -Credential $Credential -Filter "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running'" |
    ForEach-Object { $svc[$_.DisplayName] = $_ }

$svc.Values | Select-Object SystemName, DisplayName, State |
    Sort-Object State, SystemName, DisplayName |
    Out-GridView -PassThru |
    ForEach-Object { $svc[$_.DisplayName].StartService() }
```

Comment: Although this seems to be exactly what I need, once it gets to the For-each-object to start the Array is null.. 

Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.

Comment: @JonnyBoy It worked fine when I tested it. Please provide evidence. What is the value of `$svc` and what is returned by `Out-GridView -PassThru`?

Comment: PassThru shows the stopped services.
once it get passed that part though i get this.. 

Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
####################################
+     ForEach-Object { $svc[$_.DisplayName]}
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex
###################################
I took out StartService() as I do not want to start currently..

Comment: Check `$svc` if it contains a service with the given display name (or anything at all).

Comment: $svc has the Name and Value

Comment: @JonnyBoy That's not possible. Again, please provide evidence. Update your question with your current code.